# Dart: Generic constraint that requires implementation of operator []

Tags: generics, dart, operator-overloading

In Dart is it possible to have a generic constraint that requires the generic type to implement a particular operator function?

I want a generic function that accepts any type that implements `operator []`.

e.g.

```dart
void foo<T extends operator[]>(T arg) {
  var v = arg['abc']
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

The `[]` operator is just a method like any other, except for the fancy name.
The only way you can constrain a type argument to have a specific method is to require that it implements an interface which has that method, and then it only works if the argument type actually does implement that interface.

What you are asking for is a *structural* requirement on the type, and the Dart type system is mostly *nominal* (a type is defined by its name, not by its members, so something with the same members is still a different type if it doesn't implement that first type by name).

Comment: Got it. My hope was that the operator functions had some sort of implicit interface

Comment: As a second thought, perhaps Map and List can implement something called `Indexable`? Just as int and double have `Comparable`.

Comment: They could, but we don't actually *want* that. A list is kind-of a map with consecutive integer keys, but it's not the same thing. A common supertype should only exist if it's abstracting over the *same* operation, not just things that happen to have the same method name.I think we'd do `Lengthable` before `Indexable`.